# How to properly calculate linear acceleration using AcceleroMeter in Android

Tags: android, android-sensors

To my utmost surprise, in Android 4.0+ they decided to remove LINEAR ACCELERATION sensor from available software sensors and put it inside a hardware sensor, the gyroscope that is rarely available in regular phones. I don't know why they did it, but imagine my surprise when I delivered the software that was tested on a cheap 2.3 phone, and on 2 months old phone it shows *Unable to instantiate linear acceleration sensor*. Why have they done it?

To save my skin, I checked if an Accelerometer is available in the phone, and it does. Based on [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel), I should be able to calculate linear acceleration using the data from accelerometer. I checked the code and I see a variable that has no declaration available.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
  // In this example, alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT),
  // where t is the low-pass filter's time-constant and
  // dT is the event delivery rate.

  final float alpha = 0.8;
  float[] gravity=new float[]{0.0f,0.0f,0.0f}; //should it be here???

  // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
  gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
  gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
  gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

  // Remove the gravity contribution with the high-pass filter.
  linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
  linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
  linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
}
```

What does the gravity array contain in the first run?
Should I add it like

```
float[] gravity=new float[]{0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
```

?

Or should it contain real gravity data that is available via the Gravity sensor (also not available in regular devices)?

Does the calculation result proper linear acceleration data? Is it possible to calculate just by substracting a number from the incoming sensor data?

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html in Android 4.0 and later, the linear acceleration sensor is only available on devices that have gyros. "if a device does not have a gyroscope, these sensors do not show up and are not available for use."

Comment: And why did they decide to remove a sensor that available in 2.3 phones? So they consider half of the 4.0 phones (which do not have gyro) being less professional than a 2.3 phone that can measure linear acceleration. Great innovation....

Comment: yes, it stinks. Try setting the app's uses-sdk `android:targetSdkVersion` to 9 (Android 2.3) or 13 (Android 3.2). That's *supposed to* make the new OS compatible with earlier releases. It'd be great to document the results of that experiment.

Comment: [Why does "@Nestor" disappear from a comment?] @Nestor

Comment: My test project's target version was API level 10 and it worked great with a Galaxy Ace phone. When we tested it on a 4.1 phone (Galaxy Trend), the values were all 0s. So setting the target doesn't solve the issue. In 4.0 the accelerometer is supposed to be used but it is hard to use as a linear acceleration source. I reckon, removing the software sensors in 4.0 is a bad decision. Probably they put it back in 5.0.

Comment: Please do report the problem to Google/AOSP with all the details you have about the results on different phones, Android versions, and the target version experiment. Or find an existing bug report and "star" it. Even if they realize it already, it's important to know how many developers are impacted and to what degree. @Nestor

Answer (score 5):

Actually what is done in that docs provided code snippet is that they take data from accelerometer(which contains both gravity and linear acceleration) and filter it. So how it basically works, we take raw data and assume that gravity vector is something constant and cannot change very quickly, opposite to linear acceleration, which changes really fast. So let's say if we take 80% of past counted gravity vector and add 20% of raw data we filter fast linear acceleration peaks and get gravity vector. If we remove gravity vector from raw data we get linear acceleration without gravity. Google for exponential filter for more information. Here you can play with it http://copterpilot.ru/custom-app/exponential/.
So you can easily initialize your global gravity array of floats with zeros and wait a little for filtered data. Here is code snippet

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
private float[] gravity = new float[3];
private float[] linear_acceleration = new float[3];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)
    // with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant
    // and dT, the event delivery rate

    final float alpha = 0.8f;

    gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
    gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
    gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

    linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
    linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
    linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
}  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a cannonical answer, but what i know is that the actual initial readings of the acelerometer will hardly be (0,0,0), since it is not 0 when the device is not moving, because the value depends on the position of the 3 axis, and not in the movement (with the differences in the positions, we can infer the movements). So to get any relevant data you have to compare different readings. For that, i would prefer to read the acelerometer values at the beginning (in the first call to `onsensorchanged`) and then start calculating what you need starting in the second call to the function

actually, when they talk about gravity, you dont need a gravity sensor, since the acelerometer is actually that. It is measuring the gravity value for each axis, from 0 to 1

Comment: I do not understand then that why Google tells the aforementioned code to be calculating the linear acceleration? According your answer, it lacks the initial gravity readings.

Comment: I think that example is not as complete as others, since you cannot read everything, and as you said, they don't have all the variables initialized. If you initialize it with all zeros (that probably is what they are silently proposing), the code will work, and it just probably wont be a little less accurate in the first measurements. What i would do, is to start coding one of the approaches, test it out, and be ready for a small re factor if you dont think that the results are ok. The differences in the code wont be great, and probably it will be easier to understand with some data to look at

Comment: And would you verify that the linear acceleration values calculated in the code above are more or less accurate? We used the code, and when the phone rested on its back, it shows 7.5 as Z-axis linear acceleration. If the code above would correct the gravitational effects, it should show around 0.0 in every axis. It does not. If I stand the phone, the Y-axis shows 7.5.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate gravity force vector. Basically your accelerometer measures total as gravity+acceleration so you need to remove gravity force out of it. In the same article you provided there is info on how to use Gravity sensor. So listen to that sensor and update your gravity vector global variable from it.

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial post, gravity sensor is also a missing sensor in most devices, so I cannot calculate with it.